# Adding traffic lights to a junction, what is the logic of using lights with arrows?

Tags: civil-engineering, simulation, traffic-light

I'm doing a job and one of the feature is adding realistic traffic lights to junctions of a network and I have to be very specific. So, if on the ground there are arrows signaling the traffic flow (e.g., one for right turn and two for straight ahead), what are the types of traffic light bulbs that I have to use? One full bulb and one right arrow? One up arrow and one right arrow? Or two up and one right?

I'm a developer, I didn't study this kind of problems.

Comment: Visit some traffic light controlled junctions with arrows on the lights and analyse the control.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer to your question in the rules of the road for your country. This will be basic theory in the driving licence test.

In general,

- A green circle indicates permission to proceed if the way is clear. If turning right across oncoming traffic then the driver must give way.
- The green arrow in most countries means that you have the right of way in the direction indicated and that conflicting traffic movements have been stopped.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. I need the exact logic for which the lights are put on the traffic lights. If have three traffic lights and one of them is for the right turn, while the others are for the straight ahead path, what kind of bulb should I use? One right arrow and two up arrow? Or one right arrow and two circles?

Comment: Your question might be clearer if you included some images/diagrams

Comment: I think I did answer your question. You only use arrow lights when there is a right of way (or maybe if there is only one permitted route). I don't know why you would have "two for straight ahead". There is still no location information in your question.

Comment: In N.A. originally you just have a green light and a flashing green light as your options.  In my neck of the woods a flashing green light meant you had the right of way to make a left hand turn (across on coming traffic).  You could still proceed straight or turn right if they were valid options for you position at that intersection.  It was referred to as either and advanced green or a delayed green.  The solid green light gave you permission to proceed through the intersection in whatever direction you needed to go, but it did not give you right of way over on coming traffic.

Comment: When I asked a traffic engineer about why they changed from standard lights to lights with built in arrows, I was told it was basically an improvement with lighting technology that added clarity to what drivers were allowed to do.  So if there is a right/left arrow, you can now only turn that direction when the arrow is green.  You can no longer wait for a gap in oncoming traffic and go like you could under the old solid green light method.

Comment: I don't think that can be correct - or safe. At night a driver faced with a round green cannot be expected to see that there are arrow greens that are off. Round green indicates that the driver is authorised to take any legitimate route subject to traffic priority rules.